# linear search in array to add the values of matched indexes for parallel arrays

Tags: arrays, c

```
int priority[item] = {1,3,2,1,3}; //item is a user inputted number max can be 10
int cost[item] = {200,333,111,444,42};// parallel values of the items
printf("What priority do you want to filter by? [1-3]: ");
scanf("%d", &select); select can be a value of 1-3
```

I have to find all the items with priority 1 and total their cost

Filter:   by priority (1)

Total:   $311

Comment: Try a for-loop.

Comment: Is there a reason why they are in parallel arrays, rather than bundling the paired values into a struct and making an array of that? Paired arrays like this have a nasty tendency to get desynchronized.

Comment: im required to use arrays sir, will linear searching for multiple elements and add their corresponding values for cost work? but I don't know how to do that